# Apple Remote Notifications - Handle Token change

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, benchmarking

I need to use Notifications via APNS in my iPhone App.
But as I read specification, I see the Token can be changed on APNS side and I have to update token on Provider side to receive notifications right.

But what will happen when Provider creates Notification and will pass it to APNS and in this time the token will be already changed?
Will I receive a Notification with old token? Will provider be notified that token expired?

Should I solve it so, that after registering I will update my Provider with info "YOU CAN SEND NOTIFICATIONS" and make a NSTimer job to update this state while app is running?

According to this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your app registers for notifications at launch, and implements the methods specified in the documentation, it will be sure to get the correct token.

If your app keeps track of what the token used to be, it can send an update to the provider as needed (or just every time it gets a token whether it has changed or not).

If the token has changed, and the provider tries to push using the old token, the provider will be notified by the push notification server that the token is not valid.

Comment: And when token changes and Provider sends Notification to APNS while client offline or with old token while it is already new ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the token will only change when the client registers for a notification, not while it's offline. Also, they don't change that often. They can even persist across OS upgrades, so I don't think it's that big a an issue in real life.

Comment: when you read documentation i posted, you can note `An application should register every time it launches and give its provider the current token.` and `Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it`. And question persists. What will happen when Provider sends Notification while offline and You go online and on register token will be changed ?

Comment: Your app should obviously tell the provider if the token has changed, but if the token hasn't changed, there's no need for the network traffic to the provider. I wouldn't call that caching. As for token changes, I'm pretty certain that they only happen when a device requests a token from an APNS, not while it's offline. A token might have an expiration date if it's not used for a while, but if your users use your app on a regular basis, this will never be an issue, since your app will know if the token has been updated.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question POV. Client app registers and receives changed token, Provider will generate and send Notification to APNS before Client app will notify Provider about new token. How can I solve this situation?

Comment: You're right, I might have misunderstood your question. You're talking about the (very short) time overlap, where the token has actually changed, but the provider has not been notified yet, and it needs to send a push notification to the app?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover the situation where the token has changed, but the provider doesn't know yet.

Comment: thanks, that answers my question, and this discussion is also very inspirative :)